# Spark - two tables and views

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have created a view from two tables on the hive, and let's say I have

```
df = spark.select(select * from view)
```

and

```
df1 = spark.sql(select * from table1)
df2 = spark.sql(select * from table2)

df3 = df1.join(df2)
```

I assume that the condition to join in both cases is the same.

Now the question is, will the output of df and df3 be identical? Why and how?

Comment: how is "view" created?

Comment: @Young: let's say I created a view based on joining table1 and table based on some conditions.